# Using KClass as argument to templates

Tags: kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I used the following link to get around the limitations arising from type erasure in Java.

[kotlin reified generic in virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037849/kotlin-reified-generic-in-virtual-function)

I want the following class to be interfaced as follows:

```
class KlaxonJsonParserAdapter(private val klaxon: Klaxon) : JsonParser {
    override fun <T: Any> parse(string: String, type: KClass<T>): T = klaxon.parse<type>(string)
}
```

Subsequently, it enables to use it as such:

`JsonParser.parse<Type>(string: String)`

through extension functions.

But I couldn't figure out how to use the `type` parameter to external dependency as a reified type to achieve what I want.

I cannot plug the variable into the template slot as such:

`klaxon.parse<type>(string)`